# Excel VBA shows Userform randomly

Tags: vba, excel

I've just gotten into programming VBA, and have very little other programming experience.

I'll first describe the intention of the macro:

So, there are an x number of excel files with data in them. All these files follow the same basic design:
Column A contains the 'name' of the data I want. There are ten rows with different names.
Column M contains the data corresponding to the name of column A (an average value of the columns in between)
This average data has to be transferred to a 'master' excel file.

I've made a userform to select the files that need to be imported, which appears to work fine (at least selecting the files)

I call the userform within my module using

```
usrform.show
```

As said, I'm able to run the userform. Just when I click apply within the userform, it stops the code and opens the excel vba editor and displays the graphical userform.
No idea what's causing this. Do Any of you have input?

```
Public strListe_selected() As String
Public booDatenAbbrechen As Boolean

Sub Ergebnisse_einlesen()

Dim datei As String
Dim liste As String
Dim test As Variant
Dim name As String
Dim nPh As Integer
Dim Suche As String
Dim Excel_Daten() As Variant
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim rngFound1 As Range
Dim Komponente() As String
Dim startreihe As Integer
Dim SMK As String
Dim dateinr As Integer
Dim strdatumformatiert As String
Dim strerstellungsdatum() As String
Dim intantwort As Integer
Dim strdatum As String
Dim Phase As String


'*************************************Zeit messen um Einlesezeit zu optimieren
Dim t
t = Now

'*************************************Zeile controlieren, somit kein daten in die falsche zeile kommt
startreihe = ActiveCell.Row
If startreihe < 10 Then
    MsgBox "Bitte markieren sie die Zeile in der die neuen Testdaten eingetragen werden sollen und führen sie das Makro erneut aus"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Cells(startreihe, 3) <> "" Then
    antwort = MsgBox("Die markierte Zeile enthält bereits Daten, wollen sie diese überschreiben?", vbOKCancel)
    If antwort = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
End If

'************************************Sammeln von Informationen über diese Arbeitsmappe
liste = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.name
letztespalte = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
name = ThisWorkbook.name

'************************************Dialogfenster öffnen
xls_suchen.Show

If booDatenAbbrechen = True Then Exit Sub

For dateinr = 0 To UBound(strListe_selected) 'Schleife über die gewählten xls-Dateien

Application.ScreenUpdating = False                   'Bildschirmanzeige unterdrücken
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Element & strListe_selected(dateinr)  'öffnen der xls-Datei



'**********************************************************************************************************************
'neudimensionieren des ARRAYs
c = 4
emdat = anzkomp * (c + 1)
ReDim Excel_Daten(24 + emdat, 3)

'Spaltenüberschrift des Arrays "Excel_Daten" festlegen
Excel_Daten(0, 0) = "Name"
Excel_Daten(0, 1) = "Reihe"
Excel_Daten(0, 2) = "Spalte"
Excel_Daten(0, 3) = "Wert"

'**********************************************************************************************************************
'******************************** Daten aus der Excel-Datei lesen *******************************************************

i = 2
For k = 1 To anzkomp
    Suche = Komponente(k)
    Excel_Daten(i, 0) = Komponente(k)

    Set rngFound = Cells.Find(What:="Bemerkung:")
    test = Cells(rngFound.Row, rngFound.Column).Value
        If test = "Bemerkung:" Then
        anzkomp = 11
        nPh = 1
        ReDim Komponente(anzkomp)
        Testergebnis = "Phase"
        Komponente(1) = "F_eth"
        Komponente(2) = "F_Lakor_m"
        Komponente(3) = "F_lradap1c[0]"
        Komponente(4) = "F_lradap1c[1]"
        Komponente(5) = "F_lradap1c[2]"
        Komponente(6) = "F_lradap1c[3]"
        Komponente(7) = "F_lradap1c[4]"
        Komponente(8) = "F_lradap1c[5]"
        Komponente(9) = "F_lradap1c[6]"
        Komponente(10) = "F_lradap1c[7]"
        Komponente(11) = "Km_st_1"
    Else
    MsgBox "Der test ist nicht bekannt. Ist der Datei ein EDR Messdatei?"
    End If

    Set rngFound1 = Cells.Find(What:="Phase")
    If rngFound1 Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox Testergebnis & "nicht gefunden"
    Else
        Set rngFound = Cells.Find(What:=Suche, After:=Cells(rngFound1.Row, rngFound1.Column))

        If rngFound Is Nothing Then
             If Suche = "F_eth" Then n = 2
             If Suche = "F_Lakor_m" Then n = 5
             If Suche = "F_lradap1c[0]" Then n = 8
             If Suche = "F_lradap1c[1]" Then n = 11
             If Suche = "F_lradap1c[2]" Then n = 14
             If Suche = "F_lradap1c[3]" Then n = 17
             If Suche = "F_lradap1c[4]" Then n = 20
             If Suche = "F_lradap1c[5]" Then n = 23
             If Suche = "F_lradap1c[6]" Then n = 26
             If Suche = "F_lradap1c[7]" Then n = 29
             If Suche = "Km_st_1" Then n = 32

             For i = n To n + 4
                If i <> n Then Excel_Daten(i, 0) = Suche & "_PH" & i - n
                Excel_Daten(1, 3) = ""

             Next i

        Else
            Excel_Daten(i, 1) = rngFound.Row
            Excel_Daten(i, 2) = rngFound.Column
            Excel_Daten(i, 3) = Cells(rngFound.Row, rngFound.Column + 12).Value
            i = i + 1

                For j = 1 To c
                    If j > nPh Then
                        If Suche = "F_eth" Then n = 2
                        If Suche = "F_Lakor_m" Then n = 5
                        If Suche = "F_lradap1c[0]" Then n = 8
                        If Suche = "F_lradap1c[1]" Then n = 11
                        If Suche = "F_lradap1c[2]" Then n = 14
                        If Suche = "F_lradap1c[3]" Then n = 17
                        If Suche = "F_lradap1c[4]" Then n = 20
                        If Suche = "F_lradap1c[5]" Then n = 23
                        If Suche = "F_lradap1c[6]" Then n = 26
                        If Suche = "F_lradap1c[7]" Then n = 29
                        If Suche = "Km_st_1" Then n = 32
                        Excel_Daten(n + j, 0) = Suche & "_PH" & j
                        Excel_Daten(n + j, 3) = ""
                        i = i + 1
                    End If
                Next j
        End If
     End If

Next k



'Einlesen der Ergebnisse abgeschlossen --> schließen der VTS-Datei
ActiveWorkbook.Close

'**********************************************************************************************
'**********************************************************************************************
'Daten in gewünschtes Tabellenblatt übertragen

For b = 1 To 12
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(liste).Cells(startreihe, b + 1) = Excel_Daten(b, 3)
Next b
b = 12
For a = 13 To 10 + emdat

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(liste).Cells(startreihe, b + 3) = Excel_Daten(a, 3)
        If Excel_Daten(a, 0) = "GRAMS_KM_CO2" Or Excel_Daten(a, 0) = "GRAMS_MI_CO2" _
        Or Excel_Daten(a, 0) = "FUEL_CONS_MPG" Or Excel_Daten(a, 0) = "FUEL_CONS_KPL" _
       Or Excel_Daten(a, 0) = "FUEL_CONS_LP100K" Then
           b = b
      ElseIf Excel_Daten(a + 1, 0) = Excel_Daten(a, 0) & "_PH1" Then
         b = b + 2
        End If


        For i = 1 To c
            a = a + 1
            b = b + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(liste).Cells(startreihe, b + 3) = Excel_Daten(a, 3)
        Next i
        b = b + 1
        'If a < emdat + 10 Then
           ' If test = "US06V1_FE" And VTS_Daten(a + 1, 0) = "FUEL_CONS_MPG" Then B = B + 5
        'End If
Next a

Application.ScreenUpdating = True                  'Bildschirmanzeige zulassen





Next dateinr







End Sub
```

Userform:

```
Private Sub button_cancel_Click()
ReDim strListe_selected(0) 'Liste wird gelöscht
booDatenAbbrechen = True
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub button_all_Click()

With Me.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        ListBox1.Selected(i) = True
    Next
End With

End Sub

Private Sub button_none_Click()

With Me.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
    Next
End With

End Sub

Private Sub button_apply_Click()
booDatenAbbrechen = False


With Me.ListBox1
liste = .List
j = 0
For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
    If .Selected(i) Then
        ReDim Preserve strListe_selected(j)
        strListe_selected(j) = liste(i, 0)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next

End With

Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub button_add_file_Click()
add_files
End Sub

Private Sub button_add_folder_Click()
add_folder
End Sub



Sub add_folder()

Dim objAppShell As Object
Dim varBrowseDir As Variant
Dim strPfad As String
Dim varUnterordner As Variant
Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim varOrdner As Variant
Dim Element
Dim strFilelist() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strFile As String
Dim FD As FileDialog

Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FD
    .AllowMultiSelect = True

    If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show = 0 Then

    Else
    strPfad = .SelectedItems(1)
End If



End With


If strPfad = "" Then Exit Sub

'Ordner nach *.xls-Dateien durchsuchen
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set varOrdner = objFileSystem.GetFolder(strPfad)
Set varUnterordner = varOrdner.SubFolders

i = 0
ReDim Preserve strFilelist(i)

'Hauptordner durchsuchen
strFile = Dir(strPfad & "\" & "*.xls") 'Ersten Eintrag wählen

Do While strFile <> ""
    strFilelist(i) = strPfad & "\" & strFile
    ListBox1.AddItem (strFilelist(i))
    i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve strFilelist(i)
    strFile = Dir    'strFile = Dir 'Get nächsten Eintrag.
Loop

'Unterordner durchsuchen
For Each Element In varUnterordner
    strFile = Dir(strPfad & "\" & Element.name & "\" & "*.xls")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        ReDim Preserve strFilelist(i)
        strFilelist(i) = strPfad & "\" & Element.name & "\" & strFile
        ListBox1.AddItem (strFilelist(i))
        i = i + 1
        strFile = Dir    'strFile = Dir 'Get nächsten Eintrag.
    Loop
Next

End Sub

Sub add_files()

Dim FD As FileDialog
Dim Element
Dim i As Integer

Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With FD
.AllowMultiSelect = True
'.InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.xls"""
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Excel dateien", "*.xls"
End With

i = 1
If FD.Show = -1 Then
    For Each Element In FD.SelectedItems

'       datei = Dir(Element, "*.xls")
        ListBox1.AddItem (FD.SelectedItems(i))
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You can just copy-paste your code and select it and use CTRL+K to format it .. if that doesnt work work you just add code as text and I will format it for you. I think we do need to see it. Also, when it takes you to the VBE does it highlight any code in (by default) yellow?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't highlight anything..
Also, the ctrl+k worked :) thanks for that. I added the code to the first post.

Comment: Try to change `Unload Me` in the apply button for `Me.Hide` and then `Unload usrform` in the Module1 when youre done working with it

Comment: where would I put this `Unload usrform` (I typed it like `Unload(usrform)` because it was suggested by the editor to do so) statement?
At least it doesn't show the usrform in the editor anymore. Data doesn't get entered into the masterfile.
Maybe thats another bug I need to sort out?